# Use #IF directive to detect unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, directive

I have this specific call in my code and I found the config needs to be different when running the full app as to when I'm testing using an integration unit test.

Is there a way to check for a call from a unit test using the `#if` directive?

```
#if TestMethod
...do this config
#else
...do this config
#endif
```

Maybe someway to detect an attribute on the unit test function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, because either the code exists in the built binary or it doesn't. The decision is made *entirely* at compile-time, so there's nothing you can do at execution time to reintroduce the "missing" code. You'd have to dynamically load one of two different binaries, and run the tests that way.

Do you *have* to use conditional compilation, instead of deciding which route to take at execution time?

Comment: Was looking for an easy way then just commenting and uncommenting code. Did not want to waste more time digging thru structure map. Originally the test ran fine, then when the app ran, threw an error at this one line. Was hoping for a fast easy solution then commenting code. Now that i see directives as a compile time event its makes perfect sense why it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to handle the caller context from your code; particularly if you are trying to test the logic within it. If, however, you want to execute some function with different parameters (for example) depending on whether you are executing it in application or test context, then you could either use some base type or interface as the parameter, or tag the method with an attribute and check the attribute using reflection. The directives are to be used to determine what code should be compiled and you should only use them if you are certain that's what you are intending.